# Need to hide a block when an element is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide

I am using this code to show a "login box" when you click in the text area for comments (WordPress blog).

```
$('#comments textarea').click(function() {
    $('#comment-user-details').slideDown("slow");
});
```

The form will show up only if a user is not logged in.

However, since I'm using the "Simple Facebook Connect" plugin to allow commenting with FB profile, when a user is logged in with Facebook, the "login box" is loaded, and the plugin hides it by adding a "display: none;" class, but since I got the above code on, when a user clicks in the textarea, the "login form" appears, obviously.

I tried to check if a plugin element is loaded (the block "Logged in as…"), to say "use my above function only if this element is not loaded", something with this:

```
if ($("#fb-user").length == 0) {
   $('#comments textarea').click(function() {
      $('#comment-user-details').slideDown("slow");
   });
}
```

But the problem is that the plugin loads its block after the script, so for the script the element never exists.

So came across the Live Query plugin, which seemed the way to go, but still, can't find the right logic for the code:

```
$('#fb-user').livequery(function() { 
        if ($("#fb-user").length == 0) {

        $('#comments textarea').click(function() {
            $('#comment-user-details').slideDown("slow");
        });

    }
```

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried checking the length of #fb-user *inside* the click command?

Comment: Yep! That worked!
I guess I'll have to go with the common "how the hell did I not tried that one out?".

Comment: No problem! Sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code:

```
$('#comments textarea').click(function() {
        if ($("#fb-user").length == 0) {
            $('#comment-user-details').slideDown("slow");
        }
    });
```